# Replace Spaces in Column Name with Underscore MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have inherited a MySQL database that contains many columns in many tables that have spaces in their names.  I have been asked to change all spaces in column names to underscores.  Is there a way to do this with a script?

I thought that I can get them all listed with a SELECT from information_schema.... but I am not sure how to I can do the replacement.

My logic would be that if the column name contains a space, replace it with an underscore.  But I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Would you consider a simple Python script to do that for ya?

Comment: I am unsure on how to run a Python script.  I would consider it though!

Answer (score 2):

if you have the privileges, you would do the following:

```
UPDATE COLUMNS SET COLUMN_NAME = REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, ' ', '_')
```

But most likely, you cant alter the schema.

Comment: Something like this? update information_schema.TABLES a
        join
    information_schema.COLUMNS b ON a.TABLE_Schema = b.TABLE_SCHEMA 
set 
    b.COLUMN_NAME = REPLACE(b.COLUMN_NAME, ' ', '_')
where
    a.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOURDBNAME';

Comment: @ThinkCode: "The target table b of the UPDATE is not updatable" :D

Comment: Try on a test table first!!

Comment: yea, it could be very dangerous. only test on test database first.

Comment: What is the verdict m RANDALL?

Comment: I want to be sure I limit it to my test database.

Comment: Yup, apparently I cannot update that.  Damn.  "not updatable"

Comment: I believe I have to use ALTER TABLE.

Answer (score -1):

```
update information_schema.TABLES a
        join
    information_schema.COLUMNS b ON a.TABLE_Schema = b.TABLE_SCHEMA 
set 
    b.COLUMN_NAME = REPLACE(b.COLUMN_NAME, ' ', '_')
where
    a.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOURDBNAME';
```

Raheel Hasan's should be the right answer if you have the privileges for information_schema database.